# sql oralce ошибка - формат даты не распознан

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF') from dual;
```

Вот запрос, кусок `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF')` просто с документации скопировал, заменив только на sysdate не работает. Как это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спецификатор формата [`FF`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) (дробные доли секунды) применим только к типу данных TIMESTAMP (именно такой тип имеет поле таблицы в тексте [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129)) и неприменим к типу данных DATETIME (именно такой тип данных возвращает функция [`SYSDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions207.htm#SQLRF06124)).

> ```
> select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF') from dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-01821: date format not recognized
> ```

> ```
> select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF3') from dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-01821: date format not recognized
> ```

> ```
> select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> | TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SS') |
> | :--------------------------------------- |
> | 14-MAY-2020 06:03:03                     |
> ```

> ```
> select TO_CHAR(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF') from dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> | TO_CHAR(CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP),'DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SSXFF') |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 14-MAY-2020 06:03:03.000000                                  |
> ```

> ```
> select TO_CHAR(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF3') from dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> | TO_CHAR(CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP),'DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SSXFF3') |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | 14-MAY-2020 06:03:03.000                                      |
> ```

> ```
> select TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF') from dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> | TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SSXFF') |
> | :----------------------------------------------- |
> | 14-MAY-2020 06:03:03.906859                      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5501b7cfc3bc4036a47fb154f6924b77)*

Обрати внимание - `SYSDATE` не возвращает дробные доли секунды вообще.